# Need REGEXP Matching in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, regex

I want to match a String which looks like this:

```
[lang_de]Hallo![/lang_de][lang_en]Hello![/lang_en]HeyHo[lang_es]Hola![/lang_es]
```

I want the matching to return true if there is text which is not enclosed by lang_tags (in this example: `HeyHo`). It could also be positioned at the beginning or end of the string.

Whitespace should NOT match, e.g. `[lang_de]Tisch[/lang_de]       [lang_en]Table[/lang_en]` should not cause a match.

I can't use lookahead or lookback, because MySQL doesnt seem to support this.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
'^ *[^[ ]|\\[/lang_[a-z]{2}\\] *[^[ ]'
```

This is how you can use it:

```
select * 
from <table> 
where <field> regexp '^ *[^[ ]|\\[/lang_[a-z]{2}\\] *[^[ ]'
```

It should handle all cases:

- Before
- After
- Middle
- Not whitespace

Comment: I can't really fully understand your REGEX (bear with me I'm noobish), but it seems to work ;)

YOU are my ROCKSTAR!

Comment: If this is the solution you chose and worked for you, you should mark it as so. It should be right by the vote up/down indicator.

Comment: I'll try to explain it: The first part of the regex (everything up to the '|' character) will try to match a non whitespace non '[' character at the start of the string, thus if your string starts with 'A[lang...' it will return true cause of the 'A'. Next, we're looking for an ending [/lang] tag and then checking for the same exact regex as before (i.e. not whitespace, not '['). This will cause '...[/lang_en]A[lang...' to match cause there was an 'A' after the closing lang tag. This will also handle the case of text at the end of the string e.g. '...[/lang_en]A'.

Answer (score 0):

my best attempt is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE ('[lang_de]Hallo![/lang_de][lang_en]Hello![/lang_en]HeyHo[lang_es]Hola![/lang_es]' NOT REGEXP '^(\\[lang_[a-z]{2}\\][^\[]*\\[\\/lang_[a-z]{2}\\])*$')
```

Let us know how you got on.

Comment: The problem with this regex is that the * operator is greedy so it doesn't work with the test data provided. So what will happen is your first [lang_*] will match [lang_de] and the second [/lang_*] will match all the way to [/lang_es]. So it won't repeat at all and think that it matched successfully. It will however solve the problem of text in the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: Yes true, i'm always bitten by .*

Comment: True, happens me quite often... learning to regexp is quite hard