# MySQL REGEXP matches a boundary word only but excluding the match in html tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, word-boundary

Following this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125464/mysql-regexp-to-match-the-whole-word-only), I still have a bit trouble in the result I get,

For instance,

`REGEXP '>[^<]*lau[[:>:]]'` will match '*lau*' only but not '*laurence*' which is correct.

`REGEXP '>[^<]*men[[:>:]]'` will match '*empowerment*' and '*women*' which are **not** what I am after.

`REGEXP  '( |>|$)home( |<|$)'` will match '*home*' only but not '*home!*' which it **should**.

How can match these correctly?

For instance,

```
Home - match
HOME - match
welcome home! - match
home is far! - match
hometown - not match
xxhomexx - not match
<a href="home.html">Hello</a> - not match
<p class="home">a box</p> - not match
```

It should **not** match any occurrence in html tags. 
home-town - not match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about 
    REGEXP '>[^<]*[[:<:]]home[[:>:]]' ?

Besides, I am really interested in the performance of your solution... Why don't you have another column in your table, which contains the text having the html tags stripped. You are then able to make good use of the full text search, instead of having a complex regexp.

Comment: `Why don't you have another column in your table, which contains the text having the html tags stripped.` I never thought about this... but `REGEXP '>[^<]*[[:<:]]home[[:>:]]` seems to work fine. thanks.